# How to replace a PDAnnotationLink's default action with PDActionJavaScript one?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to find all PDAnnotationLink in a document and replace their default actions with PDActionJavaScript ones.
The final goal is to make the link open in a new tab but for now I just want alert to be displayed on click.
Here is the test example:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDAction;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionJavaScript;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionURI;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationLink;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 *
 */
public class PdfBoxTest {

    @Test
    public void testReplaceLinks() throws Exception {

        String pathPrefix = ...path to pdf file with links...;

        Path originalPdf = Paths.get(pathPrefix + "links_test.pdf");
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(originalPdf.toFile());
        doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().forEach(page -> {
            try {
                page.getAnnotations().forEach(pdAnnotation -> {
                    if (pdAnnotation instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
                        PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) pdAnnotation;
                        PDAction action = link.getAction();
                        if (action instanceof PDActionURI) {
                            PDActionURI uri = (PDActionURI) action;
                            PDActionJavaScript javaScript =
                                new PDActionJavaScript("app.alert(\"" + uri.getURI() + "\");");
                            // actual goal of replacing the links is to open them in a new tab/window
//                            PDActionJavaScript javaScript =
//                                new PDActionJavaScript("app.launchURL(\"" + uri.getURI() + "\", true);");
                            link.setAction(javaScript);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new RuntimeException(t);
            }
        });
        Path modifiedPdf = Paths.get(pathPrefix + "links_test_mod.pdf");
        doc.save(modifiedPdf.toFile());
    }
}
```

but the document just renders the link label which is not clickable (no alert is shown).
I'm sure I'm missing something here.
Here are the links to the PDF files.
Original:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/notwf6yde5okh7g/links_test_orig.pdf?dl=0
Modified:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bejj6rawwjrbyyc/links_test_mod.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I tried your code on the AddAnnotations.java example and it worked fine. Maybe these annotations have more elements, please share a PDF. Alternatively post a screenshot of them from PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've updated the question with the test code and links to the PDF before/after

Comment: one more detail, the original PDF was created by wkhtmltopdf

Comment: It shows the alert with Adobe Reader DC when clicking. (Of course one needs to click on the yellow warning bar first. Maybe you're in a corporate environment with extra security so that JS is always disabled?)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr you are correct in the desktop app it works but my goal was to be able to do this for the document loaded in the browser. It seems that in the browser JavaScript in PDF is disabled

Comment: Maybe the viewer in the browser doesn't support javascript.